# Searching for users and displaying their profile details in search results Django

Tags: django

I am creating a blog site where users can search other users using their first_name, last_name which belong to the user model. and the search result will show

first_name, last_name, username( from user model)
profile_image, city, country from (user_profile model)

Below is my models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
country = models.CharField(max_length=100)
profile_image = models.ImageField(default='', blank=True, null=True)

def __str__(self):
    return "Profile of {}".format(self.user.username)
```

Below is my views.py

```
class ProfileList(ListView):
model = User
template_name = 'accounts/profile_list.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(ProfileList, self).get_queryset()
    query = self.request.GET.get('q')
    if query:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(user__username__iexact=query)|
            Q(user__first_name__iexact=query)|
            Q(user__last_name__iexact=query)

        )
    return queryset
```

Below are my Templates

```
<div class="col-md-8">
# I know this is not correct        
{% for user in User.objects.all %}
        {{user.first_name}} {{user.last_name}}
        {{ user.profile_image.url }}
        {{user.username}}
        {{ user.profile.city }}
        {{ user.profile.country }}

        {% endfor %}
        </div>
```

I am again just learning Django any help is greatly appreciated. I have been hitting error after error trying to resolve this

[image]

The code below got rid of the error but the search does not return any results

```
class ProfileList(ListView):
model = User
template_name = 'accounts/profile_list.html'

def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(ProfileList, self).get_queryset()
    query = self.request.GET.get('r')
    if query:
        queryset = queryset.filter(
            Q(profile__user__username__iexact=query)|
            Q(profile__user__first_name__iexact=query)|
            Q(profile__user__last_name__iexact=query)

        )
    return queryset
```

Comment: So what's your error ?

Comment: @Zulu I am not sure I think its in the template. I am not able to get any search results

Comment: @Zulu I may have misunderstood your question I have attached a screenshot of the error

Comment: But the error page gives you a traceback and where are the problematic lines.

Comment: @Zulu I was able to change the views and get rid of the error but now the search is still not returning any results. (see edits)